# Mongo aggregation add corresponding elements of two arrays of same length per document

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a document collection that looks like:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5ef9a4149dd4092813097df6"),
        "numchoices" : [
                7,
                7,
                8
         ],
        "totchoices" : [
                7,
                7,
                8
        ]
}
```

I want to add the corresponding elements of the two arrays and create one resulting array.:

```
result: [14,14,16]
```

What is the best way to do this in a pipeline? $unwind seems to only work on one array a time, giving 3x3 docs if I have two steps..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[$zip](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/zip/) can be used in order to get an array of 2-element arrays where `numchoices` and `totchoices` are inputs. Then you need [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/index.html) to output a new array:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            result: {
                $map: {
                    input: { $zip: { inputs: [ "$numchoices", "$totchoices" ] } },
                    in: {
                        $add: [ { $arrayElemAt: [ "$$this", 0 ] }, { $arrayElemAt: [ "$$this", 1 ] } ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/1fTFYW0dub0)